# Java Loop InputStream until boolean = false

Tags: java, boolean, inputstream, stringbuilder, tasklist

I have this input stream that checks if I have a certain CAD file open or not. I am doing this by using an input stream to run a tasklist command with the name I want to check. I currently have a boolean that returns true if the specific CAD file isn't open. If the CAD file is open, it returns false. However, I want it to be able to loop this until the CAD file is open because as of right now I have to keep running it in order for it to work. I also need to be able to check this boolean from a separate class. I have it in my main right now so i could test it. My code looks like this...

```
public class AutoCadCheck {

public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

    String notOpen = "INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria";
    StringBuilder textBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String command = "tasklist /fi \"windowtitle eq Autodesk AutoCAD 2017 - [123-4567.dwg]";
    int i;

    InputStream myStream = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command).getInputStream();

    while ((i = myStream.read()) != -1) {
        textBuilder.append((char) i);
    }

    String output = textBuilder.toString();
    boolean logical = output.contains(notOpen);

    if (logical) {
        System.out.println("DWG Not Open");
    } else {
        System.out.print(output);
    }
    myStream.close();
}
}
```

My other class is going to have an 'if statement' that checks whether my boolean "logical" is false, and if so, print something. I have tried every possible method I could think of, but I cannot get it to function the way I want it to. Every other thing I found involving looping an inputstream didn't really apply to my situation. So hopefully someone can help me out in achieving what I want to do.

Comment: You can either execute above code each time you want to check if a file is open or you can create a thread which executes the code independently sleeps for a while and then executes it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by moving everything out of main and into a different class. This will make retrieving values and calling specific functions easier. Then create an object of that class in main. Once that is done, I'd create a get method for the boolean variable. Now to focus on the loop. Once the object is created in main, create a conditional loop inside of main which calls the function you need until a different condition is met. This condition might be met once the file is open. After the condition is met, it exits to another loop that relies on another conditional, such as user input.

```
public class AutoCadCheck {

public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    AutoCadFile file = new AutoCadFile();
    //loop 1 
    //Some conditional so the program will 
    //continue to run after the file has been found.
    // while(){

        //loop 2
        //check to see if the file is open or not
        //while(logical){

        //}
    //}
}
}
```

Other class

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class AutoCadFile {

private String notOpen;
private StringBuilder textBuilder;
private String command;
private int i;
private InputStream myStream;
private String output;
private boolean logical;

public AutoCadFile() {
    notOpen = "INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria";
    textBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    command = "tasklist /fi \"windowtitle eq Autodesk AutoCAD 2017 - [123-4567.dwg]";
    output = textBuilder.toString();
    logical = output.contains(notOpen);

    try {
        myStream = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command).getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void checkForFileOpen() {
    try {
        while ((i = myStream.read()) != -1) {
            textBuilder.append((char) i);
        }
        if (logical) {
            System.out.println("DWG Not Open");
        } else {
            System.out.print(output);
        }
        myStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public boolean getFileBoolean() {
    return logical;
}
}
```

Comment: I only had it in the main for my testing purposes so I could see whether it worked or not. It's actually going to be ran from a button on my JToolbar. My attempts at getting it to loop from another class failed so I decided to just revert back to when it was working and post my question like that. Anyways this seems like exactly what I was looking for! However I won't be able to test it out until Monday. I'm still going to mark this as the answer though because it looks like it'll work exactly like I want it to. If I end up having trouble with it though i'll let you know. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

> My other class is going to have an if statement that checks whether my boolean `logical` is false ...

Well, `logical` is a local variable within a method.  So no code in another class is going to be able to see it.

There are two common approaches to this kind of thing:

- Make the variable (i.e. `logical`) a field of the relevant class.  (Preferably NOT a `static` field because that leads to other problems.)
- Put your code into a method that *returns* the value you are assigning to `logical` as a result.

From a design perspective the second approach is preferable ... because it reduces coupling relative to the first.  But if your application is tiny, that hardly matters.

---

I can see a couple of other significant problems with your code.

1. When you use `exec(String)`, you are relying on the `exec` method to split the command string into a command name and arguments.  Unfortunately, `exec` does not understand the (OS / shell / whatever specific) rules for quoting, etcetera in commands.  So it will make a mess of your quoted string.  You need to do the splitting yourself; i.e something like this:

   ```
   String[] command = new String{} {
       "tasklist",
       "/fi",
       "windowtitle eq Autodesk AutoCAD 2017 - [123-4567.dwg]"
   };
   ```
2. Your code potentially leaks an input stream.  You should use a "try with resource" to avoid that; e.g.

   ```
   try (InputStream myStream = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command).getInputStream()) {
       // do stuff
   } // the stream is closed automatically ... always
   ```

Comment: Ya I was going to split up the commands but it was working fine as 1 line for my testing purposes. Could you also elaborate on what you mean by it leaks an input stream? This is the first time I have used one so i'm not an expert when it comes to stringing them together.

Comment: If an exception is thrown between opening and your `close()` call, then the `close()` won't be executed.  Result - a file descriptor associated with the stream will be leaked.  Do that repeatedly and your application will crash ... because it runs out of file descriptors.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I'll be sure to keep that in mind if i ever need to create another InputStream. Thanks for the help, I appreciate the elaboration.